# Windows7 64-bit, Pyside6, PyQt6, ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, importerror, pyside6, qt6, pyqt6

I installed PySide6 and PyQt6 by following command:

```
python -m pip install PySide6

python -m pip install PyQt6
```

But when I try to run `import PySide6.QtCore` or `import PyQt6.QtCore`, then I get this error: `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified procedure could not be found.`
But when I run `import PySide2.QtCore` or `import PyQt5.QtCore`, then all works fine.

I tried a lot of tips found on StackOverflow, but nothing helped me.

Comment: I have this same error in Windows 10, when using PyInstaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 and 8 are no longer supported by Qt6.

https://www.qt.io/blog/qt6-development-hosts-and-targets